# Am I over or under watering this jade?

Tags: watering, leaves, jade

I have this jade plant that I got over 2 years ago. I've noticed that it isn't growing larger and that the leaves are turning yellow and falling off (as you can see from the pictures below) and the leaves that are green aren't the nice dark green their supposed to be. What am I doing wrong?

As you can see the plant gets a lot of sunlight as it's on a window sill, I water it about once a week.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqMMY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbmEr.jpg

pic of the pot:[image]

Comment: Where are you in the world and can you add another photo showing the pot - its hard to tell what size the pot is in relation to the plant

Comment: I am in northen europe in a small country called estonia. I added a picture of the pot as the third link

Comment: I'm in the UK - not only have I heard of Estonia, I've  known a couple of people from there... gonna do an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your plant looks as if it's in a small black pot contained inside an outer pot. If that's the case, it needs a bigger pot, so repot into a larger container using new potting soil. Second, when you water, don't ever leave water sitting in any outer tray or pot, so make sure that is emptied  30 minutes after watering, once the plant has drained down properly.

It's likely your plant has been restricted by the size of pot, so has been unable to grow well because the root to soil ratio isn't right - its hard for a plant to take up sufficient water if the rootball is solid, and water is unable to be retained by the soil for long. Repotting it will likely solve the problem, but its clearly getting quite a bit of sun - those red edges only develop  with exposure to strong sun, so I suggest you might  like to move it somewhere it doesn't get quite so much sun, just from now till end of summer, then sit it back in that spot again, if there's room in a larger pot.

Watering should be done when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, but not so dry its shrunken from the sides of the pot. Water thoroughly, and let the excess water drain away from the bottom of the pot, and, as already said, don't leave it sitting in water in the outer pot. Reducing watering slightly in winter is a good idea, but the same rule applies - water when the surface feels just about dry.

Otherwise, more information here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/jade-plant/jade-plant-care.htm

Comment: Thanks, ill get a bigger pot for it and move it on to my table behind a few other plants so it gets less sun.

Comment: Filtered/dappled sun is fine, better than no sun at all, but not full on sun all day. Full sun should be fine again from end of August where you are...